# What does the "Number" function do in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
var num = Number(prompt("Pick a number", "0"));
if (num < 10) 
    alert("Small");  
else if (num < 100) 
    alert("Medium");  
else 
    alert("Large");
```

I'm just confused about what the `Number` is doing in this code.
What will happen if I make it like this:

```
var num = prompt("Pick a number", "0");
```

Comment: `Number` converts an object to a number.

Comment: See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number

Comment: It's called a function.  The result of what's inside of the parentheses (in this case `prompt("Pick a number", "0")` is passed to that function, code within the function executes, and the result of the function is stored in the variable `num`.

Comment: I think the question does not deserve downvote. It *is* a beginner's question, but it is *not* against the SO standards. It is well formed, concrete and clear.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number.asp Google.... Just google !

Comment: @Fundhor: I am quite unhappy how SO has become unfriendly towards the absolute beginners :( The OP is asking clearly for a concrete thing. You might have spent some time by explaining them what should have they searched for. Of course the question *is* basic, but your "UTFG" answer is not helpful at all.

Comment: Usually not that rude, but this was a question very easy to answer by just taking 2 minutes on the internet. Sorry if I might have been too rude, sincerely, and I hope at least friendly bilarge found his answer ;)

Comment: @HonzaZidek SO is not designed to be friendly. Actually, it's designed to be sort of unfriendly. It's designed to capture interesting programming problems and serve as a repository for the future. It can't accomplish that goal if it's polluted with trivial questions. The notation for downvoting explicitly says "does not show sufficient research" and "is not useful". If beginners want to avoid downvotes and close votes, they should learn how to do their own research and learning--Google, SO's own search, and MDN are good places to start. These are skills they should be acquiring in any case.

Comment: @torazaburo: nowadays maybe for most of the programming questions the first google links refers to SO. So once someone must have asked the most trivial questions even on SO. Maybe not this particular one, so let's be happy that the question and its exhaustive answer is now recorded in this knowledgebase.

Comment: @HonzaZidek Sure, but then again https://www.google.com/search?q=mdn+number.

Comment: @tozaburo: Maybe you are right. Depends on the situation of the user. Maybe he really did not know what to search for. Consider the wording: "confused about what the Number is doing in this code" - notice he is not asking for the "meaning of the JavaScript function `Number`". Maybe you could have explained him something like this: "They are built in functions in JavaScript, doing a lot of useful stuff for you. You may easily find their meaning by googling for 'JavaScript function Number'." But I may be wrong and he is just a lazy person who does not deserve our help... Not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**`Number`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) converts the passed value to a number value. Examples:

```
> Number(10)
10
> Number("10")
10
> Number(true)
1
> Number("0x11")
17
> Number("foo")
NaN
```

It performs *explicit* type conversion to a number.

There is also `String` and `Boolean` which do basically the same, but convert to a string and boolean instead.

> What will happen if I make it like this ...

`prompt` will always return a **string** value. However, in your specific example, it wouldn't actually make a difference because the relational comparison operator (`<`) will perform the same type conversion *implicitly*. I.e.

```
a < 10
// is the same as
Number(a) < 10
```

Still, I'd say it's good practice to perform explicit type conversion, since it makes it clearer in the rest of the code what type you expect.

---

**Note:** It is also possible to call `Number` with `new`, i.e. `new Number(...)`, however, that will return a number **object** instead of primitive number value. This is rarely used.